# Problen with parameters in nodejs

Tags: node.js

i am using this in command console

```
node app.js www.hellos.com/hellos?i=adfasd&pe=asdfddfdf
```

code in the file :

```
console.log(`Go to ${process.argv[2]}`);
```

but it only prints part of the url

> www. hellos .com/hellos?i=adfasd

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ampersand sign is a [bash control character](https://www.nitendratech.com/linux/bash-control-characters/), so in order to pass it as part of an argument you must either

1 - escape it by adding a backslash before it (`\&`):

```
node app.js www.hellos.com/hellos?i=adfasd\&pe=asdfddfdf
```

2 - or pass it inside a string literal:

```
node app.js "www.hellos.com/hellos?i=adfasd&pe=asdfddfdf"
```